# Updating records in SQL server with limited upload bandwidth

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, networking, append

I have a large table stored on MSAccess and need to transfer this information to a like table on SQL Server. The issue that I have is that I have limited upload bandwidth and need to find the best way to slowly send this over the network (for example 10 records at a time).

At the moment I have a linked the SQL Server table in access and I have written a simple update query that appends 10 records every 30 seconds.

My concern is that this is probably not the best way to do this and I don't understand enough about linked tables etc. to be sure of the best practice for this situation.

Has anyone got any experience of this sort of issue that could offer some advice?

Answer (score 1):

Migration or replication?

If you're doing a one-shot migration, you may want to simply export the Access data as CSV files, then move those files through regular network means to the SQL Server installation and import from the other side of the pipe.

If you're doing a regular replication for reporting server purposes, SSIS is probably the more attractive option than linked servers.  There are a number of parameters which you can experiment with to get the best results out of your particular system setup, including batch sizes, fast read options, etc.

Comment: Thanks Avarkx it is a weekly arrangement so it looks like I need to look at SSIS - although I don't have it installed at the moment.